# Change font size in WEKA Explorer

Tags: weka

I need to be able to use the WEKA Explorer GUI but make the font size bigger for displaying to an audience. I was able to change the fonts for some parts of the text by modifying the call to java in the file RunWeka.ini  Specifically, I changed the first uncommented line to

```
cmd_default=javaw    -Dswing.aatext=true -Dswing.plaf.metal.controlFont=Tahoma-plain-18 -Dswing.plaf.metal.userFont=Tahoma-plain-18        -Dfile.encoding=#fileEncoding# -Xmx#maxheap# -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=#systemProxies# #javaOpts# -classpath "#wekajar#;#cp#" #mainclass#
```

The difference from what comes with the Weka distribution is that I added the first three arguments - the ones that begin with -Dswing.  This changes the font size in many places but fails to change a few places as marked in the screen shot below.

[image: WEKA Screen Shot]

Does anyone know how to change the font size for the remaining text? Another argument to java?